# "noun + not + modifier"--- is it only for a noun

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

> In a country not their own, they suffered a great deal.

In this sentence, I can see how it works.

But we never say "in a country their own", do we?  We say " in their own country." Here is how the logic is drifted away. With adjectives, we say "good person," just as how we say " their own country." However, we neither say nor write " person not good."

> Your wife is a not a good person.
>
> Your wife is a person not good. ?????

Does this "noun + not + modifier" structure work only with nouns? Or is there any instance of this structure with adjectives?

P.S. Sorry for any wrong usage of grammar terms.

Comment: In a country near their own.  In a country like their own.  A person not so good.  A saying not unknown.

Comment: All of them have one more word in them. near, like, so, and I don't know about the last one.

Comment: The Attorney General.  The light fantastic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Fantastic

Comment: Why is it saying not unknown, not "not unknown saying?" I think it would answer my question.

Comment: Also, I did some research on it, and it said that I have to say not so good person. To make it person not so good, I should say "person not so good enough to do something." In other words, there should be additional words. Also, as to your "the light fantastic",  I don't think I see very much of them, which creates feeling that it is only seen in literary works.

Comment: "The only _thing not nice about him_ is, he is a little — funny — I don't know what to call it".  See, there is always some words that make it, the explanation after the noun, a phrase.

Comment: So why  doesn't the same go with the nouns?

Comment: What do you mean by "is there any instance of this structure (Noun + not + Modifier) with adjectives".  Do you mean with an adjective as the Modifier? Or with adjective  _replacing_ the Noun in this structure (which would make it a different structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the comments seem obtuse or sarcastic. The straight-out answer is that for the most part, this type of construction is now rare, and as you guessed, more likely to be used in a poetic or literary setting, "for dramatic effect".

I could imagine the grave-voiced movie ad narrator:
IN A WORLD NOT THEIR OWN, WHERE BIONIC MONSTERS LURK AROUND EVERY CORNER. . .

But of course you can use it with adjectives; some commenters hinted at that.

- in a room not far away. . .
- in a club not known for good jazz
- at a place not named
- the road not taken